# Is there problem with 'read' command in Bash, or in Bash itself when using multiprocessing, or may be I make some mistake?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, multiprocessing

First to mention that I do not have lot of experiences with Bash scripting.
Here is the problem that I observe:
When I execute `read` command and inside the cycle I run background processes, the `read` command misses some of the arguments in some very rare cases.
*For example:* if I `read` the output of `ls -la` for big number of video files and on each of them I execute `ffmpeg` command in a different sub-process, then **in some very rare cases there are missing some of the first parameters of `read` command**.
In that case the rest of parameters of the `ls` are wrong (having partial of their real values or wrongly assigned).
I most of the cases I have an output like this (which is correct):
`p1: '-rwxr-x---.'; p2: '1'; p3: 'uman'; p4: 'uman'; p5: '1080519'; p6: 'Jan'; p7: '27'; p8: '05:49'; p9: 'origVideo_453.mp4'`

but for very few lines I have not correct output and it is like this:
`p1: 'an'; p2: '1080519'; p3: 'Jan'; p4: '27'; p5: '05:49'; p6: 'origVideo_454.mp4'; p7: ''; p8: ''; p9: ''`

Here `p1` and `p2` are missing and `p3` should be `"uman"` but is just `"an"`. And `p3` becomes `p1`, `p4` becomes `p2`, etc, in this way `p7`, `p8` and `p9` remain without values.

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#src_dir=/tmp/text_files
src_dir=/tmp/video_files

dest_dir=/tmp/video_files_dest

mkdir -p $dest_dir

handle_video() {
  echo "handling file: '$1'"
  ffmpeg -loglevel error -i $src_dir/$1  -acodec copy -vcodec copy $dest_dir/$1
}

generate_text() {
  str=''
  for k in {1..512}
  do
    random=$(openssl rand -hex 20)
    str="${str}${random} "

    if [ $(( $k % 4 )) -eq 0 ]; then
      str="${str} ${new_line}"
    fi
  done

  echo "${str}" > $src_dir/$1
}

while read p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9; do
echo "p1: '$p1'; p2: '$p2'; p3: '$p3'; p4: '$p4'; p5: '$p5'; p6: '$p6'; p7: '$p7'; p8: '$p8'; p9: '$p9'"
  if test -f $src_dir/$p9; then
    handle_video $p9 &
#    generate_text $p9 &
  fi
done << EOF
$(ls -la $src_dir)
EOF
```

**When I run the `handle_video` not in background but in same thread** I do not have such problem (remove `&` from line 33).
First I thought the issue might be in the output of the command `la -ls` and I tried with other commands, but I saw the same kind of results - in most of the executions `read` has correct parameters but in very few cases they are wrong.

I also tried the script instead with `handle_video` (which uses `ffmpeg` invocation) to run  different function that is executed inside `read` cycle:  the `generate_text`.
To do this I comment lines 3 and 33 and uncomment lines 4 and 34.
And the interesting thing is that when executing it with `handle_video` problem exists but when executing with `generate_text` there is no such problem at all. At least I have never observed it in all my tests.
When executing it with `handle_video` I put 1200 video .mp4 files (1.1 MB each) in directory `/tmp/video_files` and run bash script.
When executing it with `generate_text` I generate 1200 empty files in directory `/tmp/text_files` and run the bash script.

I also tried to execute the `read` command with piping like this, but the result is the same:

```
ls -la $src_dir | while read p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9; do
  echo "p1: '$p1'; p2: '$p2'; p3: '$p3'; p4: '$p4'; p5: '$p5'; p6: '$p6'; p7: '$p7'; p8: '$p8'; p9: '$p9'"
  if test -f $src_dir/$p9; then
    handle_video $p9 &
#   generate_text $p9 &
  fi
done
```

Bash version is: 5.2.15(1)-release
ffmpeg version 5.0.2
Guest OS: Fedora version: "36 (Workstation Edition)"
VirtualBox 7.0.2
Host OS: is Windows 10 version: 21H2

Once again when I do not run the function `handle_video` in background (at line 33 remove the ampersand `&`) there are no problems.
And when I use instead of `handle_video` the function `generate_text` again there are no problems.
So I wonder is there problem in the `read` method and how it gets the arguments, or is there problem with bash how it is being executing multiple processes, or there is something that I do not understand.
Any help and tips are appreciated.

Here is a snippet of real output:

```
p1: '-rwxr-x---.'; p2: '1'; p3: 'uman'; p4: 'uman'; p5: '1080519'; p6: 'Jan'; p7: '27'; p8: '05:49'; p9: 'origVideo_453.mp4'
handling file: 'origVideo_448.mp4'
handling file: 'origVideo_449.mp4'
handling file: 'origVideo_44.mp4'
handling file: 'origVideo_450.mp4'
handling file: 'origVideo_451.mp4'
handling file: 'origVideo_452.mp4'
p1: 'an'; p2: '1080519'; p3: 'Jan'; p4: '27'; p5: '05:49'; p6: 'origVideo_454.mp4'; p7: ''; p8: ''; p9: ''
p1: '-rwxr-x---.'; p2: '1'; p3: 'uman'; p4: 'uman'; p5: '1080519'; p6: 'Jan'; p7: '27'; p8: '05:49'; p9: 'origVideo_455.mp4'
p1: '-rwxr-x---.'; p2: '1'; p3: 'uman'; p4: 'uman'; p5: '1080519'; p6: 'Jan'; p7: '27'; p8: '05:49'; p9: 'origVideo_456.mp4'
```

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. That said, [Don't Parse LS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) , also check why some variables might [Disappear](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) also `ffmpeg` might be [eating stdin](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: ffmpeg often consumes some of its stdin. use `-nostdin` option

Comment: Thank you very much @Jetchisel and @jhnc.
As you both advised me the `ffmpeg` is readfing `stdin` and this cased the problem.
When I added `nostdin` to `ffmpeg` command everything is OK.
Nevertheless I will go more in deep to the links that @Jetchisel suggests as they might prevent me from other issues.
Again thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. One more set of debugging tips that will make you more productive : you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the version info at the top and read the sections labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link @shellter.
It is really worthy and helpful.
Put it in my bookmarks and will have use it when need to write scripts.